# How to get the value of html radio button

Tags: html, django

In my html, I have the code below

```
...
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="account-notifications">
        <div class="card-body pb-2">
            <h6 class="mb-4">Activity</h6>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="switcher">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="switcher-input" name="new_comment_on_my_article" id="new_comment_on_my_article" checked>
                    <span class="switcher-indicator">
                        <span class="switcher-yes"></span>
                    <span class="switcher-no"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="switcher-label">Email me when someone comments on my article</span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="switcher">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="switcher-input" name="new_answer_on_my_forum_thread" id="new_answer_on_my_forum_thread">
                    <span class="switcher-indicator">
                        <span class="switcher-yes"></span>
                    <span class="switcher-no"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="switcher-label">Email me when someone answers on my forum thread</span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
...
```

There are two input fields, one is checked and the other one isn't. The user can also toggle **On** or **Off** the switch.
My problem how to get the current state of the switch *(toggled On or Off)* so that I can send the value to my Django as **True** or **False**

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something, but don't you just have to give your `<input>` fields names, so that when the form is submitted, their status comes back in the POST data?

```
<form ...>
    ...
    <input type="checkbox" class="switcher-input" name="foo_switch">

</form>
```

then in your view,

```
# IIRC checked boxes come back as "on" and unchecked ones don't come back
# memory might be incorrect
foo_switch = request.POST.get('foo_switch', 'off')
status = ( foo_switch == 'on')
```

You could also define a `forms.BooleanField`, but manually render the form fields.  Then the `<input>` element's HTML is completely under your control, but Django form processing handles obtaining the True/False value.

Comment: Actually, they all have names and id

Comment: In your code `<input type="checkbox" class="switcher-input">` no `name=`

Comment: I've added the name and id but when I do `console.log($('#new_comment_on_my_article').val())`, it returns `on` even when toggled it off. All the radio buttons are returning `on` even the ones that are not checked

Comment: It is now working. I used `console.log(document.getElementById('new_comment_on_my_article').checked)`